# Graph theory notation misunderstanding

Tags: graph-theory

I know $K_n$ means the complete graph on n vertices. But in my lecture notes it said "Consider $2K_n$. Please could you tell me what this means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2K_n=K_n\cup K_n$ is a graph with exactly two connected components, each of which is a complete graph on $n$ vertices. More generally, if $G$ is a graph and $m$ is a natural number, $mG$ is a graph which is the union of $m$ vertex-disjoint copies of $G.$